# How to display a number with fixed number of digits before the decimal?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I am looking for result `0123.56` and the following query should have worked.

```
SQL> select to_number(123.56,'0999.99') from dual;
select to_number(123.56,'0999.99') from dual
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number


SQL>
```

But it doesn't. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to convert a number to a number - try `to_char` instead:

```
select to_char(123.56,'0999.99') from dual;

TO_CHAR(123.56,'0999.99') 
------------------------- 
 0123.56
```

Note that in contrast, `select to_number('0123.56','0999.99') from dual;` will succeed because the [format specification matches](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4941/oracle-format-specifiers-to-number-vs-to-char/4946#4946), but will not return the text `0123.56` as you want - the `'0999.99'` in this case is an *input* format, not an *output* format - the number `123.56` will be returned.

Comment: `to_char` worked! Strange though. Why does `to_number` not work this way?

Comment: The result you are after is `0123.56`, which is not a number (it is a string/char/varchar/text/whatever). `to_number` [converts a text type (or a binary_double) to a `number`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4941/oracle-format-specifiers-to-number-vs-to-char/4946#4946). It is best to try and separate in your mind the concept of a number and the various ways you can present that number visually (eg leading zeros, comma thousand seperators etc) - the visual representation is not a number, it is text.

Comment: The problem with this solution, is that it left-justifies the result column, since it is now a character column. :-(

Comment: @cartbeforehorse try `to_char(123.56,'fm0999.99')`, or perhaps you want to space pad on the left?

Comment: @JackDouglas Actually, further investigation shows that it was the client-end software that was doing funny things with formatting.  Different clients manage "text-which-is-really-a-number" in different ways.  But your reference to the `fm` mask is a useful one all the same - thanks.  Good call.